# Exposing internal server to the outside world

Tags: networking, vpn, ngrok

Currently I'm using ngrok.io to expose local service (ex. localhost:3000) to the outside world. What can I do to expose internal company service that is only accessible within VPN to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the network in which your service is located.

If it's a home network, you need to make sure you're not behind your internet provider's NAT (in other words, that you have a dedicated public IP address), then log into your router and configure port forwarding to your machine. If you don't have a dedicated public IP, or just want your service to work independently from your personal machine, consider hosting it on a VPS.

If it's a company network, your system administrator should be able to handle this (after deciding whether it's appropriate).